# How do you remove this faucet adapter?

Tags: bathroom, faucet

This is the underside of the faucet installed in my RV. I cannot make out how to remove? Looks like a Phillips head screw, but the screws are different? I haven’t gone through all of my Phillips bits, but making sure it’s not the part the screws are in that actually turns.

[image]

Of course I’m upside down in a very tight area and can’t get a good look unless I take a photo. If I knew what exactly needing removing and with what tool I’d be set. Otherwise the sink may be coming out so I can see this attachment!! Any help appreciated!

Comment: I would try a wrench on the nuts.  What you think are screws might be threaded studs.

Comment: Some "Phillips-like" bits are actually JIS or Posidrive and Phillips drivers will strip them rather than work.

Comment: There's also [Prodrive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mlesu.png), just to add to the set. The top right looks stripped already, but there's not enough detail in the photo to properly identify the screw type

Comment: I think for this you’ll need to remove the faucet above first, there may be a set screw holding it to that brass spinal column looking piece, and the philips screws hold the brass piece to the counter similar to how an old-work box attaches to dry wall.  Sorry can’t think of the actual names, but that’s how my faucet installed and it looks similar to yours under the sink.  Loosen the above set screw and pull the faucet up.

Answer (score 0):

What looks like Philips head screws are posts.

They are threaded and brass cone-nuts are screwed on to the posts to hold the faucet in.

Remove the brass cone-nuts and the faucet will come out.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have to unscrew the outside part, not with Philips screwdriver but maybe with a wrench to losen it.

It looks like a hex tube that screws on to the inside part.